# H2 database PageStore causing OutOfMemoryError

Tags: h2

I'm using H2 as a simple embedded database to store less than 10,000 records but have started encountering an OutOfMemoryError.

Examining the heap dump the org.h2.store.PageStore has a retained size of almost 800mb for what should only be 5 to 10 megabytes worth of data.

What steps can I do to further debug and resolve this problem?

[image: heapdump]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was experiencing a side effect from the change in string representation made in update 7u6.

My development environment is post 7u6 whereas production was running an earlier version and I could not duplicate the issue.

It was not an issue with the PageStore at all except for the huge retained size due to the string references.

[TIL Oracle changed the internal String representation in Java 7 Update 6 increasing the running time of the substring method from constant to N](http://redd.it/1qw73v)